# Update geolocation information with setInterval

Tags: jquery, geolocation

I'm trying to get live coordinates with geolocation. I used setInterval to refress the script every 1 second but when it does it clears the lat $ lng input fields instead getting new coordinates.

```
<form action="done.php" method="post" name="position">
  <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" class="form-control" value="">
  <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="form-control" value="">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update location">
</form>


<script>
$(function (getLocation) {
    var Geo = {};
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
    function success(position) {
        Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;

        populateHeader(Geo.lat, Geo.lng);

    }
    function error() {
        console.log("Geocoder failed");
    }
    function populateHeader(lat, lng) {
        $('#lat').val(lat);
        $('#lng').val(lng);

    }
setInterval(function(){populateHeader()},1000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code clears the fields every second because you're calling `populateHeader()` without parameters in the `setInterval` callback function, which then sets both fields to `undefined`. To do what you originally wanted, the `setInterval` callback function would need to be calling `.getCurrentPosition()` again.

However, `.getCurrentPosition()` is already an asynchronous call, and if it takes 15 seconds to get a GPS fix, you would queue up 15 function calls with the one second interval. You could get around this issue by using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` at the end of your success and error callbacks, which would make sure to start the next query a second after the previous one finishes.

However, there is a simpler solution. If you have a look at the [Geolocation API documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API), it already has a `.watchPosition()` method that will fire the callback every time the location changes, accepting the same parameters as the one-time `.getCurrentPosition()` method. Using that will make your code cleaner and probably more efficient.

```
<form action="done.php" method="post" name="position">
    <input type="text" name="lng" id="lng" class="form-control" value="">
    <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" class="form-control" value="">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update location">
</form>


<script>
    $(function () {
        var Geo = {};

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                function (position) {
                    // Success
                    Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;

                    $('#lat').val(Geo.lat);
                    $('#lng').val(Geo.lng);
                },
                function () {
                    // Error
                    console.log("Geocoder failed");
                }
            );
        }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: how would i stop watching position?

Comment: @chovy `.watchPosition()` returns an integer ID that you can save. To unregister your handler and stop watching, pass the ID to `navigator.geolocation.clearWatch()`.